# Trino/Presto SQ: Replace NULL with a value only if the NULL comes after the first non-NULL value in the group

Tags: sql, window-functions, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to replace `NULL` values with a specified string. However, I want to make this replacement only for `NULL` values coming *after* the **first** non-`NULL`. Meaning, if a `NULL` value is *before* the first non-`NULL`, then keep it `NULL`.

Consider this data for example:

```bash
# | user_id | some_date  | animal  |
# |---------|------------|---------|
# | 1       | 2022-01-01 | NULL    | <~~ keep as NULL
# | 1       | 2022-01-02 | zebra   | <~~ 'zebra' is the first non-NULL value for user_id = 1
# | 1       | 2022-01-03 | lion    |
# | 1       | 2022-01-04 | NULL    | <~~ replace NULL with 'no_animal'
# | 1       | 2022-01-05 | cat     |
# | 2       | 2023-10-05 | NULL    | <~~ keep as NULL
# | 2       | 2023-10-06 | NULL    | <~~ keep as NULL
# | 2       | 2023-10-07 | dog     | <~~ 'dog' is the first non-NULL value for user_id = 2
# | 2       | 2023-10-08 | frog    |
# | 2       | 2023-10-09 | NULL    | <~~ replace NULL with 'no_animal'
# | 3       | 2024-02-03 | hamster | <~~ 'hamster' is the first non-NULL value for user_id = 3
# | 3       | 2024-02-04 | rabbit  |
# | 3       | 2024-02-05 | NULL    | <~~ replace NULL with 'no_animal'
# | 3       | 2024-02-06 | NULL    | <~~ replace NULL with 'no_animal'
```

The desired output should be:

```bash
# | user_id | some_date  | animal  | replaced_null |
# |---------|------------|---------|---------------|
# | 1       | 2022-01-01 | NULL    | NULL          |
# | 1       | 2022-01-02 | zebra   | zebra         |
# | 1       | 2022-01-03 | lion    | lion          |
# | 1       | 2022-01-04 | NULL    | no_animal     |
# | 1       | 2022-01-05 | cat     | cat           |
# | 2       | 2023-10-05 | NULL    | NULL          |
# | 2       | 2023-10-06 | NULL    | NULL          |
# | 2       | 2023-10-07 | dog     | dog           |
# | 2       | 2023-10-08 | frog    | frog          |
# | 2       | 2023-10-09 | NULL    | no_animal     |
# | 3       | 2024-02-03 | hamster | hamster       |
# | 3       | 2024-02-04 | rabbit  | rabbit        |
# | 3       | 2024-02-05 | NULL    | no_animal     |
# | 3       | 2024-02-06 | NULL    | no_animal     |
```

### SQL Dialect

I use AWS Athena that runs on Trino SQL.

#### Reproducible data

```sql
WITH my_tbl AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (1, DATE '2022-01-01', NULL),
        (1, DATE '2022-01-02', 'zebra'),
        (1, DATE '2022-01-03', 'lion'),
        (1, DATE '2022-01-04', NULL),
        (1, DATE '2022-01-05', 'cat'),
        (2, DATE '2023-10-05', NULL),
        (2, DATE '2023-10-06', NULL),
        (2, DATE '2023-10-07', 'dog'),
        (2, DATE '2023-10-08', 'frog'),
        (2, DATE '2023-10-09', NULL),
        (3, DATE '2024-02-03', 'hamster'),
        (3, DATE '2024-02-04', 'rabbit'),
        (3, DATE '2024-02-05', NULL),
        (3, DATE '2024-02-06', NULL)
    ) AS t(user_id, some_date, animal)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` with conditional `lag` ignoring nulls:

```sql
SELECT *,
  COALESCE(animal, 
    if(LAG(animal) ignore nulls over (PARTITION by user_id order by some_date) is not null, 'no_animal'))
    as replaced_null
FROM my_tbl
ORDER by user_id, some_date;
```

Output:

| user_id | some_date | animal | replaced_null |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | zebra | zebra |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 | lion | lion |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | NULL | no_animal |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | cat | cat |
| 2 | 2023-10-05 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2023-10-06 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2023-10-07 | dog | dog |
| 2 | 2023-10-08 | frog | frog |
| 2 | 2023-10-09 | NULL | no_animal |
| 3 | 2024-02-03 | hamster | hamster |
| 3 | 2024-02-04 | rabbit | rabbit |
| 3 | 2024-02-05 | NULL | no_animal |
| 3 | 2024-02-06 | NULL | no_animal |